# Schema.org type for a non-profit

Tags: schema.org

What will be the Schema.org type for a non-profit?

[`Organization`](https://schema.org/Organization) is too generic, and [`NGO`](https://schema.org/NGO) isn't suitable either.

I was hoping to find if there is any specific type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Schema.org doesn’t offer a way to convey that an `Organization` is non-profit, apart from using `NGO` (which might imply it, depending on jurisdiction).

You can watch the issue [Suggestion of an Organization subtype for non-profit / not-for-profit](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/246) for further development. My guess is that it will be a property (or a set of properties) for `Organization` instead of a sub-type.

So for now, simply use the most-specific type available, and in the future, add the property (or, if it will be a type, add the type in addition to your type).